# Write function in another script

Tags: python

I don't know what this is called in programming in general, and I would be very happy if its feasible .
I have a script let's call it **x.py**. I send this script to other PCs and remotely run it using :

```
$ python path/x.py [arguments optional]
```

This is the template of the script :

```
import sys

def post_command(output,err):
    pass

def pre_command():
    pass

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        return
    if sys.argv[1] == "pre":
        return pre_command()
    if sys.argv[1] == "post":
        return post_command()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So far so good, it's simple.
Now the problematic part, in other script I would like to receive a function implementation of **post_command() and pre_command()** and construct a "new" **x.py** that it's **post_command() and pre_command()** are the one's I got as arguments.

Template of the second script :

```
def my_post_command(output,err):
    print output
    print err

def my_pre_command():
    print 'empty'


def main():

    # "x.py".pre_command() = my_pre_command()
    # "x.py".post_command() = my_post_command()
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am open to any other solution as long as I can create a new script that I can send it remotely .

Comment: How does this remote invocation happen in the first place exactly?

Comment: i have "black box" infra structure that i can give it an arguments say "echo hello" or "python x.py" and it run it for me on other PCs (it also takes which PCs i would like to run it on), and also "black box" to copy a certain file to other PCs

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but I suspect that you can do what you want using the `import` statement. Your new script simply needs to do `import x` and then the `post_command` function defined in `x.py` will be available in the new script as `x.post_command`.

Comment: @ PM 2Ring  but the problem is that x.post_command won't run on the remote machine since there it won't exist , i want to like replace the "pass" part with the given implementation

Comment: You'll have to send the "implementation" somehow, and the sanest way to do that IMO is by uploading a file which contains that implementation.

Comment: i thought about it that way , the thing is i wanted to force the user to implement those functions by inheritance and interfaces . otherwise everyone might send his own files and run them without sticking to conventions, i thought it might be problematic :\ i'll think about something else , thanks .